# Why in camel-rabbitmq component RabbitMq connectionFactory must be specified. I am getting exception if I dont specify the connection factory bean?

Tags: rabbitmq, apache-camel, jms

I am working on the `camel-rabbitmq` component. If I dont specify the connectionFactory bean I am getting error

```
java.net.BindException:Cannot assign requested address: connect

at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:579) ~[?:?]
at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:568) ~[?:?]
at sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:588) ~[?:?]
```

But with `camel-activemq` even if I don't specify the `connectionFactory` bean it is working because it's creating the default `connectionFactory` object itself? But why it is not happenning in case of `camel-rabbitmq` component.  I want to know the reason behind it. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Because `rabbitmq` needs to connect to a remote RabbitMQ server and needs to have the information which comes from that connection bean.

ActiveMQ is a Java based broker and light-weight and can be used for testing purposes in embedded mode, and hence why Camel can auto create an embedded broker if you do not setup a connection factory when using JMS. This is not possible with RabbitMQ (its not Java based)